# Laravel pagination fails in building the correct query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I try to run this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`user`.`firstName`,' ',`user`.`lastName`) AS `fullName`" 
FROM `user`
WHERE `fullName` LIKE '%a%'
```

using the `User` model, Laravel send the following query by-itself before running my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM `user`
WHERE `fullName` LIKE '%a%'
```

which leds to `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userFullName' in 'where clause` exception. What is wrong with Laravel? How to run the above query regarding this issue?

Comment: Post your Laravel code, and more information about your database structure. This is not enough information on its own.

Comment: @Bogdan I'm afraid database structure is not helpful here. The issue is columns are not used when generating query to calculate number of rows, as mentioned by Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid in this case you should either use manual pagination or rebuild your main query to something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`user`.`firstName`,' ',`user`.`lastName`) AS `fullName` 
FROM `user`
WHERE CONCAT(`user`.`firstName`,' ',`user`.`lastName`) LIKE '%a%'
```

Otherwise when Laravel creates query to calculate number of rows it won't know what is `fullName` column (because columns are not used when generating query to calculate number of rows, just `count(*)` is used in this query.

Comment: Does Laravel pagination do any particular thing that a simple manual pagination is not able to do?

Comment: Automatic pagination launches 2 queries. When you use alias for column and use this alias in where, Laravel will fail to create count query because when running this query aliased column won't exist

Comment: Look at manually creating pagination using either an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` or `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` once you've got the data set using your query